# USB-to-serial driver for Linux

Tags: python, usb, pyserial, usbserial, pyvisa

I have a **USB device** that I need to control in Linux using `Python` and **serial commands**, it works with ASCII commands.

In Windows it works fine after I install the vendor driver and in Device Manager I see it as a COM3 port and I communicate using `pyserial` or `pyvisa` modules.

In Linux I see it as `/dev/ttyUSB1` but I cannot communicate with it using `pyserial` or `pyvisa`. The problem is that the vendor doesn't provide Linux drivers.

**How am I able to get the device behave as a serial port in Linux?**

Comment: There must already be a driver for your device in your Linux kernel; that's why you are seeing the `/dev/ttyS0` entry.  So this is not a missing driver issue.  I suggest closing this question and asking a better one that properly explains what the problem is ("cannot communicate" doesn't give us much info).

Comment: plug the thing in and do 'dmesg | tail' and see what happened.  Also, the most common problem in linux is that you might not have permissions on the serial port. Make sure you are in the dialout group.

Comment: `/dev/ttyS0` is not your USB2Serial adapter. So find the proper device file to use.

Comment: @electrogas 'dmesg | tail' output the following:

Comment: @electrogas
[53301.615703] ftdi_sio 3-3:1.0: device disconnected
[55579.152079] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[55579.284933] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=104d, idProduct=3000
[55579.284939] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

Comment: @electrogas 
[55579.284942] usb 3-3: Product: Agilis
[55579.284945] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Newport
[55579.284947] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: FT0GPY0Y
[55579.286399] ftdi_sio 3-3:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[55579.286447] usb 3-3: Detected FT232RL
[55579.286641] usb 3-3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1

Comment: @AlexP. sorry, it was /dev/ttyUSB1 but still not working

Comment: And are you a member of the dialout group? At a command line do "groups"

Comment: @electrogas yes, my user is already in dialout

Answer (score 2):

try `python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/ttyUSB1` and read the issue on https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/67 especially the version of pyserial

if this issue is related to yours possibly this also works :

> Managed to bypass this issue by passing `dsrdtr=True` and `rtscts=True` to
>   serial.Serial() ... as described here

your device is based on an FTDI chip, the inbuilt linux kernel module for this is `ftdi_sio` and `usb_serial` see http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux.pdf